# Programa para ler 4 valores e mostrar na ordem crescente

Tags: java, if

Comecei a pouco a prender sobre programação, eu meu professor passou a seguinte questão para ser feita com estruturas de seleção `If Else` em Java:

Construa um programa para ler quatro valores e os mostrar em ordem crescente.

Fiz então o seguinte programa:

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        long a,b,c,d;
       
        System.out.println("Digite um número inteiro:");
        a=teclado.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Digite mais um número inteiro:");
        b=teclado.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Digite outro número inteiro:");
        c=teclado.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Digite o ultimo número inteiro:");
        d=teclado.nextLong();
       
        if((a<b)&&(b<c)&&(c<d)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+a+b+c+d);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }
        if ((a<b)&&(b<d)&&(d<c)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+a+b+d+c);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((a<c)&&(c<b)&&(b<d)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+a+c+b+d);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((a<c)&&(c<d)&&(d<b)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+a+c+d+b);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((a<d)&&(d<b)&&(b<c)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+a+d+b+c);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((a<d)&&(d<c)&&(c<b)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+a+d+c+b);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }
        if((b<a)&&(a<c)&&(c<d)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+a+c+d);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }
        if ((b<a)&&(a<d)&&(d<c)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+a+d+c);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((b<c)&&(c<a)&&(a<=d)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+c+a+d);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((b<c)&&(c<d)&&(d<a)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+c+d+a);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((b<d)&&(d<a)&&(a<c)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+d+a+c);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }  
        if ((b<d)&&(d<c)&&(c<a)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+d+c+a);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }
```

Mas quando chega nesta parte:

```
if ((b<c)&&(c<d)&&(d<a)){
          System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+c+d+a);
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
```

Ele para de funcionar, não imprimi mais ("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: "+b+c+d+)a minha dúvida é se realmente é posso usar só If Else para está questão?

Comment: Você só imprime em 12 dos 24 casos possíveis.

Answer (score 3):

E não acredito que usando apenas `if else` seja a melhor forma para ordenar números. Isso porque a combinação de verificações para atender todas as situações em que um conjunto de números podem ser dispostos cresce exponencialmente a quantidade de números a serem ordenados.

Para saber a quantidade de verificações que devem ser feitas é só calcular o fatorial da quantidade de números a serem ordenados.

No seu caso são 4 números que significam que serão necessárias 4! combinação de `ifs` o seja você terá que fazer 24 comparações `if` para cobrir todas as possibilidades em que seus quatro números podem estar dispostos.

Caso se em seu exercício fossem solicitados 5 números você teria que fazer 120 comparações. Para 6 números seriam precisos 720 comparações.

---

Para resolver o seu problema, e evitar a explosão combinatória, eu usei um algorítimo de ordenação. O nome dele é bubble sort e é um algoritmo de ordenação dos mais simples. A ideia é percorrer o vector diversas vezes, e a cada passagem fazer flutuar para o topo o maior elemento da sequência.

O algorítimo do bubble sort é esse aqui:

```
faça
    declare :trocado falso
    para cada elemento no vetor até o penúltimo faça
      se os elementos não estão na ordem certa 
         trocar elementos de lugar
         atribua verdadeiro para :trocado
      fim se
    fim para
fim faça se :trocado for falso
```

Se quiser mais informações sobre o bubble sort tem na Wikpedia: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Se quiser ver como as pessoas usam o bubble sort de uma pesquisada aqui na página: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bubble+sort

## Solução

Troquei as variáveis `a`,`b`,`c`  e `d` por um vetor `long[] valor`, de quatro posições , pois será mais fácil de trabalhar com o bubble sort.

Implementei o bubble sort em linha, direto, no seu código. Está contido no laço `do while`.

Também importei `java.util.Arrays;` Somente para facilitar a impressão do vetor `valor` no final do código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays; // Para imprimir os valores no final


public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);

        // Troquei as variáveis a,b,c,d por um vetor, pois será mais fácil de trabalhar com o bubble sort

        long[] valor= new long[4]; 

        System.out.println("Digite um número inteiro:");
        valor[0]=teclado.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Digite mais um número inteiro:");
        valor[1]=teclado.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Digite outro número inteiro:");
        valor[2]=teclado.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Digite o ultimo número inteiro:");
        valor[3]=teclado.nextLong();

        teclado.close(); // Libera recursos de System.in

        boolean flag; // Flag será usada para indicar se foi feita uma troca

        do {
            // A cada iteração é marcado como se não houvesse ainda troca
            flag = false; 

            // Percorre por todos os elementos menos o ultimo, 
            //pois serão comparados o elemento com seu seguinte
            for(int i=0; i < valor.length - 1; i++) {

              // verifica se os elementos estão na ordem certa
              if (valor[i] > valor[i + 1]) {

                  // Se não estiverem ordenados os troca de lugar
                  long aux = valor[i]; // Variável para auxiliar para troca dos valores
                  valor[i] = valor[i + 1];
                  valor[i + 1] = aux;

                  flag = true;// Indica que hove uma troca
              }
            }
        } while (flag); // Se hove uma troca o algorítimo continua.

        System.out.println("Os números digitados na ordem crescente são: " + Arrays.toString(valor));

    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Espero que ajude você... Fiz de forma rápida em PHP. Não foi muito testado

```php
$a = 4;
$b = 2;
$c = 8;
$d = 6;

$primeiro = $a;
$segundo = 0;
$terceiro = 0;
$quarto = 0;

// verificando primeiro numero
if ($b < $primeiro) {
    $primeiro = $b;
}elseif($c < $primeiro) {
    $primeiro = $c;
}elseif ($d < $primeiro) {
    $primeiro = $d;
}

// verificando segundo numero
if($a > $primeiro) {
    $segundo = $a;
} else {
    $segundo = $b;
    if($c < $segundo) {
        $segundo = $c;
    }elseif ($d < $segundo) {
        $segundo = $d;
    }
}

// verificando terceiro numero
if($a > $segundo) {
    $terceiro = $a;
} else {
    if($b > $segundo) {
        $terceiro = $b;
    } else {
        $terceiro = $c;
        if($d < $terceiro) {
            $terceiro = $d;
        }
    }
}

// verificando quarto numero
if($a > $terceiro) {
    $quarto = $a;
} else {
    if($b > $terceiro) {
        $quarto = $b;
    } else {
        if($c > $terceiro) {
            $quarto = $c;
        } else {
            $quarto = $d;
        }
    }
}


echo $primeiro .' - '. $segundo .' - '. $terceiro .' - '. $quarto;
```

Comment: A pergunta é sobre **Java**.

Comment: para quem sabe realmente programar a linguagem é irrelevante ... assim como fiz em PHP poderia ter executado em qualquer outra linguagem.

Comment: Está na pergunta: "... **comecei a pouco a prender sobre programação**, eu meu professor passou a seguinte questão para ser feita com estruturas de seleção If Else **em Java**..." . Leia [Como escrever uma boa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), qualquer dúvida faça o nosso [Tour]